# Neo4J Plug In Won't Compile Due to Version Mismatch

Tags: intellij-idea, neo4j, runtime

I have seen variants of this question asked, but I have not seen an answer that was accepted.  I am using IntelliJ IDEA to simply compile the TraversDemo sample plug in that Neo4J posted on GitHub.  When I run mvn clean package I get no errors.  But when I actually tried putting the .jar file into my plug ins folder on Neo4J Desktop . . . neo4j didn't recognize the plug in.  So, I assumed something was wrong with my .jar file and I just tried to 'build' the java file in IntelliJ.  When I did, I get this error:

Module 'TraversalPlugIn' production: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/neo4j/annotations/api/PublicApiAnnotationProcessor has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 54.0

I have checked and rechecked my Java (for Windows 10) is Java 8.  I checked the Java Configuration GUI and asked for updates.  It said I had the most recent version.  Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?  I already tried screwing around with various options in Build,Execution,Deployment Java compiler. No combination seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this.  The solution was: (i) cut existing java code (and POM file); (ii) delete original project altogether; (iii) create a new maven project but choose JDK 16 as SDK this time; and (iv) paste Java code and POM xml into new project.  Then I built it, and ran maven clean package, inserted the target snapshot into the plug ins folder and ... it finally worked.